# How to show GridView inside Login with databind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, loginview

If outside the loginView, the gridview can show correctly!

Put inside Login View and use below code

```
<LoggedInTemplate> 
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
  </asp:GridView>          
</LoggedInTemplate>

((GridView)LoginView1.FindControl("GridView1")).DataSource = query;
((GridView)LoginView1.FindControl("GridView1")).DataBind();
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

> Line 22: ((GridView)LoginView1.FindControl("GridView1")).DataSource = query;

How to show GridView inside Login with databind in c#?

Comment: Did you tried just *GridView1.DataSource = query;*? and than *GridView1.DataBind();* Because  *((GridView)LoginView1.FindControl("GridView1"))* is null.

Comment: try finding the control after checking Request.IsAuthenticated possibly in the page load.

Answer (score 0):

If login is a button in your application, then at the end of that code file, you have to write and you have to make one query to select that table.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [table_name];   // here, you can take table name which you want to bind
```

After that, you have to fill dataAdapter by dataset, and that dataset is bound via following code:

```
ds = databind();
```

Comment: It's the LoginView, standard component from ToolBox, inside login view, only enable group role can view

Comment: by the way whitch qurry you use in this?

Answer (score 0):

The `<LoggedInTemplate />` is only available after the user logs in. The NullReferenceException will occur if you try to access the grid before the user logs in. I would suggest you add a check like this

```
if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    GridView gv = ((GridView)LoginView1.FindControl("GridView1"));
    if(gv != null)
    {
        gv.DataSource = query;
        gv.DataBind();
    }

}
```